# Is it possible to animate UISlider thumb image when state changes, similar to iOS Podcasts App?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uislider

I want to animate a UISlider thumb image changing when the user touches the thumb.

I set image of different sizes for different states, like this

```
    if let image = UIImage(systemName: "circlebadge.fill") {
        let small = image.applyingSymbolConfiguration(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(textStyle: .footnote))
        slider.setThumbImage(small, for: .normal)
        
        let large = image.applyingSymbolConfiguration(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(textStyle: .largeTitle))
        slider.setThumbImage(large, for: .highlighted)
    }
```

It changes but I want to add some animation to this transition, similar to the iOS Podcasts app.

Is it possible at all, using a normal UISlider?